# How can update multiple rows with a single sql query?(with "order by")

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this user table here:
(I want to update ranking based on score)

Here is SQL Fiddle :

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2f459d/1/0

Also code review :

```
create table users2 (  
     ranking int ,
     user_id int auto_increment primary key, 
     user_n varchar(70) charset utf8mb4 not null comment 'username',
     score int default '0' null, 
     constraint username  
     unique (user_n)  );
```

With values :

```
INSERT INTO users2 (user_id, user_n, score)
value(1,'mohamad',50),
     (2,'john',100),
     (3,'nik',150),
     (4,'sara',200),
     (5,'tom',250);
```

I want to update ranking based on the score. I can select but I can't update that :

```
SELECT c.u_rank,a.user_id,a.user_n,score from users2 a LEFT JOIN (SELECT @s:=@s+1 u_rank,user_id
FROM users2 d,(SELECT @s:=0) as b order by d.score DESC )  AS c
ON a.user_id = c.user_id order by score DESC
```

My efforts so far :

```
UPDATE users2 a LEFT JOIN (SELECT @s:=@s+1 u_rank,user_id
 FROM users2 ,(SELECT @s:=0) as b ORDER BY score DESC )  AS c
ON a.user_id = c.user_id  SET a.ranking = c.u_rank
```

Comment: I think it is worth considering why you want to store the ranking - it will intrinsically represent a point in time and can age / go inaccurate very easily. Can you afford to calculate it on the fly to be accurate?

Comment: Your current update query should work. Are you getting any error ? Although as @Andrew suggested, you should consider calculating it on fly, if scores will be dynamic (ranking will change)

Comment: I'd use an INSERT query for this, with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: Andrew, if this query was working my problem will be fixed:

UPDATE users2 a LEFT JOIN (SELECT @s:=@s+1 u_rank,user_id
 FROM users2 ,(SELECT @s:=0) as b ORDER BY score DESC )  AS c
ON a.user_id = c.user_id  order by score SET a.ranking = c.u_rank

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya, it's worked but not based on the score

Comment: Caius Jard, I want more performance and more speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using variables by setting the variable *first* and then using `ORDER BY` in the `UPDATE`:

```
SET @s := 0;

UPDATE users2 u
    SET u.ranking = (@s := @s + 1)
    ORDER BY score DESC ;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f62dc2/1) is a SQL Fiddle.